# Running a method on click of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

All I want is to run my code after I have clicked the `JLabel` but for some reason it's just not working and I can't work out why> There are no errors in IDE or console.

```
final JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                Main.class.getResource("/com/daniel/status1.png")));
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.EAST);

        lblStatus.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent  arg0) {
            System.out.println("Clicked") 
            });
```

Comment: 1) Use an undecorated `JButton` with an `ActionListener` to provide a better user experience. 2) Use `@Override` notation for compile time checking.  3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could achieve it would be something like:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Click me");
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { System.out.println("Clicked me!"); }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
```

But, as suggested, it would be better to use a `JButton` here, with an `ActionListener`:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Push me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Pushed me!");
            }
        });
```